# 2SLS with a discretized endogenous variable

Tags: 2sls

Imagine you would like to estimate by OLS the following:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1 med + \beta_2 high + u$$
$med$ and $high$ are dummy values with respect to some underlying variable $x \in [0,\infty)$.
$$
  med =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x>a$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
  high=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x>b$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

We also have that $b>a>0$.
$x$ is endogenous, so $med$ and $high$ should also be endogenous. Fortunately, we have some potential instrument $z$. To estimate the model, I would however need two instruments. One for $med$, one for $high$. My question is:

**What are potential ways to construct such a vector of instruments?**

I have the following idea:

$$
  z_{med} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $z>c$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
  z_{high} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $z>d$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
Where $c>d$, and $c$ and $d$ are chosen as follows:
Let $F(x)$ be the cumulative density function (cdf) of $x$. Let $\alpha=F(a)$ and $\beta=F(b)$. Let $G(z)$ be the cdf of $z$. Then $c=G^{-1}(\alpha)$ and $d=G^{-1}(\beta)$.
Do you think this is a reasonable approach? In gerenal I would probably like to have a strong first stage.

Comment: Sorry I might be reading it wrong, but won't the sum of med and high always be 1?

Comment: No, if $x \in [0,a]$, $med$ and $high$ are both $0$.

Comment: Aha, didnt see the assumption of $a > 0$.